# What's an idiomatic way to traverse and update data structures functionally in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, set

I'm coming from a Python-heavy background and trying to learn Scala through a basic "Design a Parking Lot" exercise. I have Scala code that looks something like:

```
class ParkingLot(spaces: Set[ParkingSpace]) {
    var openSpaces: Set[ParkingSpace] = spaces;
    var usedSpaces: Set[ParkingSpace] = Set()

    def assign(vehicle: Vehicle): Boolean = {
        var found = false;
        for (s <- openSpaces) {
            (s.isCompatibleWithVehicle(vehicle)) match {
                case true => {
                    if (!found) {
                        s.acceptVehicle(vehicle)
                        openSpaces -= s
                        usedSpaces += s
                        found = true
                    }
                }

                case _ => {}
            }
        }

        found
    }
}
```

The logic is pretty simple - I have a ParkingLot with Sets of open and occupied ParkingSpaces. I want to define a function `assign` that takes in a Vehicle, loops through all the openSpaces and if it finds an available space, will update the open and used spaces. I'm having a hard time coming up with a good idiomatic way to do this. Any thoughts and suggestions about how to reframe questions into a Scala mindset?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that would help. Even if we had a Map[ParkingSpace, Boolean], can you provide an idea how to functionally traverse + update that map?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Scala... could you provide a quick code snippet?

Comment: Note that we only want to update ONE ParkingSpot, even if multiple are able to take the Vehicle.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, yesterday was already too late. I added an answer with two alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with this code is use of mutable state (`var`). Rather than changing an existing object, functional code creates new, modified objects. So the functional approach is to create a new `ParkingLot` each time with the appropriate allocation of spaces.

```
case class ParkingLot(open: Set[ParkingSpace], used: Set[ParkingSpace])
{
  def assignVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle): Option[ParkingLot] =
    open.find(_.isCompatibleWithVehicle(vehicle)).map { space =>
      ParkingLot(open - space, used + space.acceptVehicle(vehicle))
    }
}
```

`assignVehicle` can return a new parking lot with the spaces appropriately updated. It returns an `Option` because there might not be a compatible space, in which case it returns `None`. The caller can take whatever action is necessary in this case.

Note that `ParkingSpace` now as an `acceptVehicle` that returns a new `ParkingSpace` rather than modifying itself.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a loooot more sense. I'm still wondering about the immutability vs. performance tradeoff, is it typically "ok" in Scala to tradeoff the time complexity of function to gain immutability? It looks like assignVehicle now potentially copies over the entire set every time it is called.

Comment: It is a valid concern and there are performance implications, though they are not usually significant unless dealing with very large amounts of data. Since objects are held by reference it is cheap to copy unchanged parts of an object, and collections such as `Set` will be implemented in a way that makes the add/remove operations efficient. But, yes, if you have a time-critical part of the code it may be necessary to use mutable values *internally*, but always keep the interface functional.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Just to make sure I understand this - ```it may be necessary to use mutable values internally, but always keep the interface functional``` -> this means that we should still return new ParkingLots, but we could have the underlying data structure be mutable?

Comment: Yes, in theory, though in this case it is hard to see how it would help. Mutability is normally used to accelerate algorithms within a method which can be done functionally but are significantly faster when mutable. `ListBuffer` is a good example of this which is used internally to build `List` objects but not exposed in the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

As also the answer by @Tim mentioned, you need to avoid mutations, and try to handle this kind of state managements in functions. I'm not gonna dive into the details since Tim mentioned some, I'm just proposing a new approach to the implementation, which uses a map of spaces to weather they're used, and returns a new (not optional) instance every time you assign a new vehicle (if the vehicle fits in, updated instance is returned, and if not, the same instance):

```scala
class ParkingLot(spaces: Map[ParkingSpace, Boolean]) {

  def withVehicleAssigned(vehicle: Vehicle): ParkingLot = 
    spaces.collectFirst {
      case (space, used) if !used && space.isCompatibleWithVehicle(vehicle) => 
        new ParkingLot(spaces.updated(space, true))
    }.getOrElse(this) 

}
```

Almost the same process goes for removing vehicles, the usage would be something like this:

```scala
parkingLot
  .withVehicleAssigned(v1)
  .withVehicleAssigned(v2)
  .withVehicleRemoved(v1)
```

Comment: This could be even better if it was `Map[ParkingSpace, Option[Vehicle]]` so it stored which `Vehicle` was in each slot :)

Comment: @Tim Yeah I though about it, but also thought that maybe the space holds the optional vehicle its keeping. Since in vehicle removal, you need to know weather that specific vehicle is actually parked in the space, so only knowing weather the space is populated or not would not be enough (based on the current modeling of the question)

Comment: @Tim although I still believe that what you mentioned (`Map[Space, Option[Vehicle]]`) is better, since space is not responsible to know which vehicle its holding!

Comment: Very clean! Seems like functions like: ```collectFirst```, ```getOrElse```, ```find```, etc are pretty handy when parsing collections. Is there any where I can find a list of these and their definitions?

Comment: @scalanoob I suggest you use the scaladoc. Although, to understand those functions, and some more important functions such as `map`, `flatMap`, etc,. it's better to also have a minimal understanding of functional programming itself.

Comment: Got it, yeah map + flatMap + fold, etc. I'm familiar with from my Functional Programming Language class! Generally have an understanding of the operations, just wasn't sure how Scala represented them with syntax

Answer (score 1):

Since most answers already explained the importance of immutability and creating new objects, I am just going to propose two alternative models and solutions.

#### 1. Using a queue of empty spaces plus a set of used ones.

```scala
final case class ParkingLot(freeSpaces: List[ParkingSpace], occupiedSpaces: Set[ParkingSpace]) {
  // Returns the used space and the new parking lot.
  // An option is used since the parking lot may be full.
  def assign(vehicle: Vehicle): Option[(ParkingSpace, ParkingLot)] =
    freeSpaces match {
      case freeSpace :: remainingSpaces =>
        val usedSpace = freeSpace.withVehicle(vehicle)
        Some(copy(freeSpaces = remainingSpaces, usedSpaces = usedSpace + usedSpaces))

      case Nil =>
        None
    }
}
```

#### 2. Using a `List[(ParkingSpace, Boolean)]` and a tail-recursive function.

```scala
final case class ParkingLot(parkingSpaces: List[(ParkingSpace, Boolean)]) {
  // Returns the used space and the new parking lot.
  // An option is used since the parking lot may be full.
  def assign(vehicle: Vehicle): Option[(ParkingSpace, ParkingLot)] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: List[(ParkingSpace, Boolean)], acc: List[(ParkingSpace, Boolean)]): Option[(ParkingSpace, List[(ParkingSpace, Boolean)])] =
      remaining match {
        case (parkingSpace, occupied) :: tail =>
          if (occupied) loop(remaining = tail, (parkingSpace, occupied) :: acc)
          else {
            val usedSpace = parkingSpace.withVehicle(vehicle)
            val newSpaces = acc reverse_::: ((usedSpace -> true) :: tail)
            Some(usedSpace -> newSpaces)
         }

        case Nil =>
          None
      }

    loop(remaining = parkingSpaces, acc = List.empty).map {
      case (usedSpace, newSpaces) =>
        usedSpace -> copy(newSpaces)
    }
  }
}
```

> Note, the boolean may be redundant since the `ParkingSpace` should be able to tell us if it is empty or not.